# Intuition behind Topological Spaces, Intersection Property

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am in an introduction to Topology course and I was unsure about the intuition I have on a couple questions required to be handed in. So here goes:

Let X be R, the reals, and let Omega consists of the empty set and all infinite subsets of R. Is Omega a topological structure?

Let X be R, the reals, and let Omega consists of the empty set and complements of all finite subsets of R. Is Omega a topological structure?

For the first question, intuitively I think it is a topological space but couldn't a finite intersection of such elements in Omega be a finite subset, namely the empty set or any intersection of elements such that the set only has finite elements contained in it.

For the second question, again I think it is a topological space but I am having trouble grasping fully if the intersection of such elements in Omega can be finite.

Any hints and advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection of two infinite subsets can be finite, for instance the sets $(-1,0]$ and $[0,1)$ are both infinite but have a finite intersection.

The intersection of two cofinite sets, however, will always be cofinite. If $\Bbb R\setminus F_1$ and $\Bbb R\setminus F_2$ are both cofinite (which means that $F_1, F_2$ are finite), then the complement of their intersection is $F_1\cup F_2$, which is finite.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts about the first question. I had the same idea for a counterexample written down. In regards to the second question, when does one set(or rather the union of sets) go from finite to countable? Since we can have a finite intersection of such cofinite sets, wouldn't the union of finite sets eventually grow to an infinite size?

Comment: The union of an infinite number of finite sets can of course be infinite, so the complement of the intersection of infinitely many cofinite sets may not be cofinite.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks Stefan.